# How to align card title when using Boostrap-Vue

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I'm using boostrap-vue's `<b-card>` and hitting an issue where I can't seem to center align the title prop. Anyone know a good way to do this? Below is the contents of my card, which has a dynamic title, img-src and also sub-text (which is actually center-aligned, unlike the title):

```
    <b-card
      :title="obj.name"
      :img-src="mainImage()"
      img-alt="project info"
      img-top
      tag="article"
      style="max-width:30rem"
      bg-variant="dark"
      text-variant="white"
      class="mb-3 text-center"
    >
    <a class="subtext card-block stretched-link text-decoration-none" :href="endpoint()">
       {{ obj.subtext }}
    </a> 
    </b-card>
```

Comment: the `text-center` should work according to the docs, check with dev tools on whats applying it left.. though the component renders to standard bootstrap [cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/) dom, with a few more lines you might as well just use own code (right-click inspect element, copy/paste) vs trying to work around the component implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [b-card-title](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/card#comp-ref-b-card-title) inside `b-card`.

```
<b-card-title class="text-center">{{obj.name}}</b-card-title>
```